# How to convert num to date in R? - 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, date

I read my SPSS file to R and the date variables didn't convert as dates. Instead they look like this : Datevar1: num 13666752000. How to convert it to a date format? I tried `df$Datevar1 <- as.Date(df$Datevar1)`and it gave me: 'origin' must be supplied.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPSS Dates start from 1582-10-14](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/idh_idd_dtwz_learn.html), and the number is in seconds. So you just need to supply the origin and divide the number by 86400.

```
as.Date(13666752000/86400, origin = "1582-10-14")
```